# You are running a Trial version of SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, plugins, nopcommerce

Question regarding to nopCommerce website.

I have created a ECommerce website using nopCommerce.
nopCommerce is a open source ECommerce web application.
SevenSpikes providing a plug-ins for nopCommerce web site.
I'm using two free version plug-ins from SevenSpikes. But the plugin throwing an error on every third to fourth of reload of website. The error as

```
'You are running a Trial version of SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.MegaMenu'

'You are running a Trial version of SevenSpikes.Nop.Plugins.InstantSearch'
```

I had checked the network and console using Developer tools in browser, but every thing is fine. I think plug-in [authors of plugin] is intentionally showing an error on every third to fourth reload of the page.

I'm doing it in localhost, but [here](http://www.nu-agemedspa.com/clients/nuage/store/c/9/revitalash?orderby=11&pagesize=4&viewmode=list) is the sample url has same issue. `[Re-Load 3 to 4 times]`

Any one has any thoughts to solve this error is very useful.

Comment: I don't know why negative marks, add comments I can understand if I i did a mistake

Answer (score 6):

From nop forum:

> Please note that the trial version of the Menu is for evaluation
>   purposes only. We understand that the trial message could be
>   frustrating during development and we will consider showing it less
>   often. As you have already started to modify the styles of the Menu
>   then it seems like you are going to use the plugin, so it would be
>   best for you to get the full version now rather than later and get rid
>   of the trial message.

So if you want to remove trial warnings, buy the full licence.

Link: http://www.nop-templates.com/boards/topic/366/trial-messege